# how to use common class for all view controllers of uitabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7

I have a UITabBarViewControllers having 4 ViewControllers with 4 NavigationController embedded in using storyboard. I am putting button as left navigation item in all 4 ViewControllers which will animate programatically created UIView like in screenshot below. [image]

Now the problem here is that I had to write same code in all 4 ViewControllers. And if I need to make major changes in future, I will have to change code in all ViewControllers. I don't know how to solve this problem? What is the best solution for this. This isn't feasible way to code. And I'm new to iOS development, so be specific when you explain. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a BaseViewController that is inherited by all other view controllers. And you can add required methods in BaseViewController that will be available in all other view controllers.

Eg.

This is going to be a super class of all the other classes.

```
MenuBaseViewController.h
————————————————————————————
@interface MenuBaseViewController : UIViewController 

//declare properties and methods here

- (void)showMenu;
- (void)hideMenu;

@end

MenuBaseViewController.m
————————————————————————————
@implementation MenuBaseViewController

//implement methods here

- (void)showMenu {

//logic for showing menu
//probably you need to set rootViewController what is selected.
//You can create method for setting root view controller in AppDelegate

}

- (void)hideMenu {
//logic for hiding menu
}

@end


OneViewController.h
————————————————————————————
@interface OneViewController : MenuBaseViewControlle 

//declare properties and methods here

@end

OneViewController.m
————————————————————————————
@implementation MenuBaseViewController

//implement methods here

//you can call showMenu, hideMenu to show/hide menu

@end
```

In the same way you need to inherit MenuBaseViewController in all other view controller and call showMenu/hideMenu method to show or hide menu.

Comment: That is the thing I don't know how to perform.

Comment: See edit..I've tried to give you an idea that how can we implement it.

Comment: Thank you for bothering to write code. I get idea how to do this. I even tried this before. But the problem I faced was, ViewController could't perform Action of any button created in common class. It is easy to show menu, hide menu. But interaction with elements in side menu was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one super class like `SuperCommonVC` and write all common functionalities that all of your 4 controllers will have.

Ex : Super common

```
@interface SuperCommonVC:UIViewController
{
}
@end
```

Now you just need to extent `SuperCommonVC` to all your 4 controllers like

Ex : VC1

```
@interface VC1:SuperCommonVC
{
}
@end
```

This is just simple inheritance. Now you could have all functionality of SuperCommonVC to your VC1 and others as you want.

Comment: I am so confused. Never did that before. Can I find tutorial for that?

Comment: Well its a basic concept of Object Oriental Programming. For instance you can look into `UIViewController ` class which you always `extend` to your new VC class. The point is, your VC class will have all the functionality that you have defined in Super. E.g. viewWillAppear will call of Super first than your VC's like so.

Comment: see this example :http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.in/2011/08/improved-uiviewcontroller-subclass.html

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. I have solve my problem with some steps.

Following are the steps for solve you problem.

1. Make your view controller shown in screenshot (view controller
           containing left and front view controller) as `rootViewController`
           of main `UINavigationController`(initial view controller).
2. Your 4 viewcontrollers should be `UIViewController` not
           `UINavigationController`.

After perform above changes your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it would be more helpful if you had explained how to do that in detail? Are you saying that I only need one NavigationController for all 4 ViewControllers? And how can I achieve that in storyboard? I guess one NavigationController can embed only one ViewController

Comment: Take one custom class of `UINaviagtionController`. Then set the left bar button in that custom class and make one object of this(say customNav).Then set selected `UIViewcontroller` as `rootViewContoller`` customNav.) This way your problem will be solved.

Comment: OKay, I will give a try on this one. Btw I found that you are also a Gujju. I have poked you on FB.